'Laravel new <name>' not prompting for options
When I attempt to install a new laravel project using:
laravel new exampleproject

I'm not prompted for anything:  Breeze/Livewire/Vue/react etc.  or preferred database type at the end of the install.
It just goes ahead and fully installs a Laravel project with random defaults, as though I've applied some kind of --noprompt argument.
(Obviously I know I can manually install/configure whatever I want afterwards, but I just want to understand why this is happening and get it working).

Make sure you are using the latest version of laravel/installer.
laravel -V

Also confirm that PHP8.2 or higher.
php -v

If installer is not version 5, install it again.
composer global require laravel/installer


Thank you so much!  I was stuck on v4 of the laravel installer.
